# Not working trigger place_changed of Google places autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, triggers, google-places

This is my input html

```
 <input id="autocomplete" type="text" class="postulantes_search_location" 
    value="" onFocus="geolocate()">
```

it's work fine when i write an address and select an option of the dropdown. The problem is when i set a text, for example:

```
$('#autocomplete').val($(this).children('.saved-location').text());
```

and execute the trigger:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete, 'place_changed');
```

and then, the function `autocomplete.getPlace(`) return `undefined` !

Answer (score 1):

If it's still relevant, your problem is that `google.maps.event.trigger` actually has three parameters, and you don't pass a place with your trigger:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(autocomplete, 'place_changed', {...} /*actual place data*/)
```

but you probably don't want that, because you don't have a place, just a string, so you shouldn't trigger the event, and should write your own processor, that, e.g., makes a request to `google maps api`, like this:

```
$http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + $('#autocomplete').value() + '&key=' + GOOGLE_API_KEY
```

or any other method you'd like